# Integers which give a solution in real numbers for ax+cy = e and bx+dy = f and no integer solutions mod n.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Stumped on another question while studying for my Number Theory final and I would like some help. The question is as follows:

*Find integers a, b, c, d, e, f and positive integer n > 1 for which there is a solution in real numbers x and y for the simultaneous equations*

*ax + cy = e*

*bx + dy = f*

*and yet there is not a solution in integers x and y for the simultaneous congruences:*

*ax + cy ≡ e (mod n)*

*bx + dy ≡ f (mod n)*

I began by trying to find integers that satisfy the first condition and when looking at the markscheme, the answer was given to be "Any value where ad - bc ≠ 0 but also IS 0 mod n (or at least relatively prime to n)"

I don't really understand how they arrived at that solution. I'd really appreciate some pointers! Thanks!

Comment: Just pick $a=n$, $c=0$, $e=1$, and any suitable $b,d\ne 0,f$.

Comment: The question states that n > 1. But if c = 0 and e = 1 then ax = 1. As a and x both are integers, a has to be 1 which makes n = 1 which would be out of bounds. Could you please give me some other pointers? Thanks!

Comment: @Shanker $ax = 1$ has a solution in reals, where $x$ is not an integer.  But $n x = 1$ does not have a solution in integers mod $n$.

Comment: Oh! Missed out that part, thank you for making me aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

If the determinant $ad - bc \ne 0$, there is always a real solution (in fact a rational solution).  But if $n$ is prime and $ad - bc \equiv 0 \mod n$, there are $e,f$ such that there is no solution mod $n$.  This is because Cramer's rule works in any field.

EDIT: In slightly more detail, the classical adjoint of the matrix $A = \pmatrix{a & c\cr b & d\cr}$ is $\text{adj}(A) = \pmatrix{d & -c\cr -b & a\cr}$.  It satisfies $\text{adj}(A) A = \det(A) I$. If $A \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr} = \pmatrix{e\cr f\cr}$, then $\text{adj}(A) \pmatrix{e\cr f\cr} = \det(A) \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}$ (and this works in any commutative ring, in particular the integers mod $n$, whether $n$ is prime or not).  So if 
$\det(A) \equiv 0 \mod n$ but $de - cf \not \equiv 0 \mod n$ or $-be + af \not \equiv 0 \mod n$, there is no solution mod $n$.